# ValidFormBuilder prepopulate fields and preset checkboxes

Tags: validform

What's the correct way to prepopulate fields when loading a form that is meant to edit preexisting data, such as a user profile?  Also, bonus points to the answer that also includes setting the checked status of check boxes or radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Initial values for a form field in ValidForm Builder can be set using the "default" key of the "meta" array like this:

```
$objForm = new ValidForm("test");

$objCat = $objForm->addField(
    "name", 
    "Name", 
    ValidForm::VFORM_STRING, 
    [
        "required" => true
    ],
    [
        "required" => "Don't leave me empty"
    ], 
    [
        "default" => "Arthur Dent" // <= This key sets the initial value
    ]
);
```

This works for ALL fields in VFB, also check boxes, radio buttons and select fields.

For list type fields like check boxes, radio buttons and select fields the initial value can also be set using the third parameter of the `addField` method.

```
$objForm = new ValidForm("test");

$objSelect = $objForm->addField(
    "rating", 
    "Rate ValidForm Builder", 
    ValidForm::VFORM_SELECT_LIST
);

$objSelect->addField("Awesome", 1);
$objSelect->addField("Great", 2);
$objSelect->addField("Super Cool", 3, true); // This item is selected by default
$objSelect->addField("Splendid", 4);
$objSelect->addField("Best thing ever happened", 5);
```

The above code snippet is from the examples on Github. 
https://github.com/validformbuilder/validformbuilder/blob/master/examples/select-default.php

There is also an example on how to set multiple initial values on a multi select field.
https://github.com/validformbuilder/validformbuilder/blob/master/examples/meta/checklist-with-multiple-default-values.php

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I just didn't realize it was so obvious.